# Splitting a string on a numeric value using Regex in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, split, numeric

I have a string of format:

```
"one two 33 three"
```

I need to split it on the numeric value so that I get an array of length 2:

```
"one two"
"33 three"
```

or an array of length 3:

```
"one two"
"33"
"three"
```

I tried `Regex.Split(str,"\D+")` but it gave me:

```
""
"33"
""
```

and `Regex.Split(str,"\d+")` gave me:

```
"one two"
"three"
```

and `Regex.Split(str,"\d")` gave me:

```
"one two"
""
"three"
```

So none gave me the desired result. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?=\b\d+\b)
```

Split on this regex.

This uses a positive lookahead to check if at the point of split there is an integer separated by word boundary.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wV5tP1/5

EDIT:

If you wanna remove the space too use

`(?=\d+\b)`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wV5tP1/6

Comment: Worked like a charm! Could you please explain to me what exactly does it do? Thank you

Comment: this will give you a space next to the string `two`

Comment: I have encountered a small problem - some strings contain numeric values as part of a non-numeric string, and this regex splits a string on it. I only need to split on those numeric values that are separated by whitespaces. For example if a string is "ghx-3n 454 test" the regex creates 3 strings, "ghx-", "3n", and "454 test" and I only want two: "ghx-3n" and "454 test". Could you  modify it slightly?

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookahead in your regex like,

```
Regex.Split(str," (?=\d+)")
```

`(?=\d+)` Positive lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by a number. So the above regex would match the space which exists just before to the number. Splitting according to the matched space will give you `"one two" "33 three"` as result.

```
Dim input As String = "one two 33 three"
Dim pattern As String = " (?=\d+)"
Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, pattern)
For Each match As String In substrings
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match)
Next
```

Output:

```
'one two'
'33 three'
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/OVUR0r)

To get an array of length 3.

```
Public Sub Main()
Dim input As String = "one two 33 three"
Dim pattern As String = " (?=\d+)|(?<=\b\d+) "
Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, pattern)
For Each match As String In substrings
Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match)
```

Output:

```
'one two'
'33'
'three'
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ueax9g)

Comment: that gave me an array of 3 values:  {"one two","3" "3 three"} and I wanted  {"one two","33" "three"}